# How to most effectively test a react component with a nested child component with conditional props

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-testing-library, react-testing

So I’ve read posts and watched tutorials on using Enzyme to test that a nested component is rendered with the correct props. I’ve also read the seemingly contradictory recommendation in the official react testing docs guidelines *against* testing component instances. This leaves me confused as to whether or not it is helpful to test whether nested components are rendered with the correct props.
[image]

As an example, here is a component with a nested component where the child component takes various prop values depending on the parent's props. Would it make sense here to test the props of the nested Decision components?

[image]

/* Parent Component */

```
import Decision from "./Decision";

interface BookProps {
    age: number;
    boring: boolean;
    chapters: number[];
}

const Book = ({ age, boring, chapters }: BookProps) => {
    if (age < 10) {
        return (<Decision
            bookDescription={chapters.length > 0 ? 'a chapter book' : 'prose'}
            shouldAssignToStudents={boring && chapters.length > 10}
        />)
    } else {
        return (<Decision
            bookDescription={'old'}
            shouldAssignToStudents={false}
        />)
    }
}
export default Book;
```

/* Child Component */

```
interface DecisionProps {
    bookDescription: string;
    shouldAssignToStudents: boolean
}
const Decision = ({ bookDescription, shouldAssignToStudents }: DecisionProps) => {
    return (<div>
        {`This book is ${bookDescription} and the 
        students ${shouldAssignToStudents && 'do not '} need to read it`}
    </div>);
}

export default Decision;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to test that a component is called with certain props, you need to test that the output is what you'd expect given some input.

e.g. a single test case could be passing an `age` less than 10 to `Book` would produce a certain HTML/text output. Remember a component is just a function at the end of the day, and the best true unit test would test that inputs produce outputs.

For testing `Decision` directly its even more simple really, you can call it with different values of `shouldAssignStudents` and confirm the output is what you'd expect. Anything that involves branching logic to determine output can be tested directly.

> the official react testing docs guidelines against testing component instances

Yes and actually thats a reason Enzyme has fallen out of favor. Its API's focus on testing component instances which is not a good way of testing components. You can test with Enzyme the idiomatic way but you'll end up ignoring the `props()` APIs, and end up exclusively testing with APIs like `.containsAnyMatchingElements`,

If you are open to it you should consider [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) instead. Its APIs are focussed on testing component output rather than testing component instances themselves.